# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Sequel Pro with MySQL on my Mac. I return the error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' " every time I attempt to run this sql query. The Database is created successfully, but the table is not. Can anyone advise where the error in my syntax is? I simply do not see it:

```
CREATE DATABASE bamazon

USE bamazon;

CREATE TABLE products
(
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `department_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `price` int NOT NULL,
    `stock_quantity` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

Comment: You have a comma on the `PRIMARY KEY` line.

Comment: Thank you I am new to this!

Comment: Please read [mcve]--if you minimized this code you'd find the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query does not work because there is an extra comma (,) at the end. Remove that and it will work. The correct syntax will be:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    department_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    price int NOT NULL,
    stock_quantity int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this!

Answer (score 3):

Please remove the ',' after PRIMARY KEY (id). It should be like this

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 product_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 department_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 price int NOT NULL,
 stock_quantity int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```